# Node JavaScript - decimal string to integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a `Node.js module` which returns a value that I need to convert into a string or a `64-bit integer`.
The returned value looks like this:

`{ low: 214107458, high: 17825793, unsigned: true }`

The documentation states that it is something called `decimal string`. I am not sure what that means.
The value I want is suppose to look like this: `76561198174373186`

How can I convert it?

This is the module that I get the value from:
https://github.com/seishun/node-steam

To be specific, this code: https://github.com/seishun/node-steam/blob/84cc4f870b8da4755ba057acff336a093891458f/lib/handlers/friends/index.js

This is the module that I need to send the converted value to: https://github.com/Lwatt/node-steam-userinfo/blob/master/index.js

My code:

```
steamFriends.on('friendMsg', function(steamID, message, type) {
    if(type != Steam.EChatEntryType.ChatMsg) return;
    steamuserinfo.getUserInfo(steamID, function(error, data){
        if(error) throw error;
        var datadec = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.response)); //This returns an empty array because steamID is in incorrect form.
        console.log(steamID); //Output: { low: 214107458, high: 17825793, unsigned: true }
    });
});
```

Comment: Javascript does not have 64-bit integers.  There are some libraries out there that might help , for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/UInt64

Comment: decimal means 10based number and string is still string. This is probably a hack / workaround for lacking 64 bit integer support as John already mentioned.

Comment: I see. However string is fine too. Is there a way to convert this to one string that looks like this "76561198174373186" or should I use that library?

Comment: done some formatting. But include the link of documentation, citations from documentation, and name of the module that you are using.

Comment: I have added the modules and the snippet from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure what that means

It works like this:
76561198174373186 = 17825793 * 10^32 + 214107458

NB for converting to a "76561198174373186" string, the easiest way would be to use a 64 bits integers supporting lib, G.I.Y.F.